# Adding users from txt file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a project that consists of adding users to the OS and these users are in a text file.
I have written this so far but it isn't working.
Can you tell me what's wrong?

The file `user.txt` is:

```
charbel:password:1001:1001:Charbel Haddad:/home/charbel:/bin/bash:0:30:15:7:y
assil:p@ssw0rd:1002:1002:Assil:/home/assel:/bin/bash:0:30:10:5:n
marwan:p@ssw0rd:1003:1003:Marwan Ghantous:/home/marwan:/bin/bash:0:50:30:7:n
michel:password:1004:1004:Michel:/home/michel:/bin/bash:1:30:10:5:y
```

Script:

```
FILE="user.txt"

USERNAME=$(cut -d " " -f 1 $FILE)
PASSWORD=$(cut -d " " -f 2 $FILE)
USER_ID=$(cut -d " " -f 3 $FILE)
GROUP_ID=$(cut -d " " -f 4 $FILE)
USER_INFO=$(cut -d " " -f 5 $FILE)
HOME_DIRECTORY=$(cut -d " " -f 6 $FILE)
SHELL=$(cut -d " " -f 7 $FILE)
MIN=$(cut -d " " -f 8 $FILE)
MAX=$(cut -d " " -f 9 $FILE)
INACTIVE=$(cut -d " " -f 10 $FILE)
WARNING=$(cut -d " " -f 11 $FILE)

useradd -m -c "${USERNAME}" "${PASSWORD}" "${USER_ID}" "${GROUP_ID}" "${USER_INFO}" "${HOME_DIRECTORY}" "${SHELL}" "${MIN}" "${MAX}" "${INACTIVE}" "${WARNING}"
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? For example, did you print out the variable values to check whether they are what you expect?

Comment: Please add user.txt to your question (no links, no comment).

Comment: In what way isn't it working?  Does `user.txt` contain just one line of data?  What do you get from `echo "[[$USERNAME]]"` before the `useradd` command?

Comment: Which distribution and version do you use?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there are actually 4 lines of data each line consisting of a user with its fields

Comment: This question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @Cyrus: no — this is about shell programming and is on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: no — this is about syntax of `useradd` and not shell programming.

Comment: @ElenaAssaf — then you get output like `[[user1` – `user2` – `user3` – `user4]]` from the echo command I gave (where the dashes represent newlines — you can't format comments very much).  That shows you what the problem is, does it not?

Comment: @Cyrus — this is about the use of `cut` on a multi-line file and the values stored in the shell variables of the shell ***program*** that the OP is trying to write.  The semantics of `useradd` are coincidental to the issue.

Comment: @ElenaAssaf: add the `user.txt` file to the question where it can be formatted.  Why are you specifying space as the delimiter between fields in the `cut` commands when the file uses colons?  You're going to need a variant on `while read -r line; do …processing of one line…; done < user.txt`.  Or you might futz with `IFS` to split the lines on colons and use `read -r USERNAME PASSWORD … WARNING`.

Comment: See also [How to debug a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951352/15168)

Comment: There's your problem;  your fields in the file are `:` delimited, but you're telling `cut` to use **space** as a delimiter.

Comment: @tink so i just have to put ":" instead of " " ?

Comment: Using `cut` also makes each variable a *list* of values. You want to split each line separately, using `read`.

Comment: That will **cure** the immediate issue; there may be, as @Cyrus pointed out, problems with the way you use `useradd` as well ...

Comment: While shellscripting is clearly about programming, it matches much better the https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

Independently of any issues related to the invocation of `useradd`, there are multiple problems in the way you're extracting the data from the data file:

1. The field separator in the file is a colon, but you use `cut -d " "` to split on spaces.
2. When you process a file with 4 lines, the value in `$USERNAME` will contain 4 names, one per line.

To read the data, I recommend setting `IFS=:` and using `read` in a loop to read the fields and process the results.  You might end up with a script a bit like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=:
while read -r usename password user_id group_id user_info home shell min max inactive warning
do
    echo useradd -m -c "$usename" "$password" "$user_id" "$group_id" \
         "$user_info" "$home" "$shell" "$min" "$max" "$inactive" "$warning"
done < data
```

It would probably be best to leave the `< data` out of the script, or use `cat "$@" | while read …` so that data can come from other places than just the file `data`.  Given your input, the output is:

```
$ bash script.sh
useradd -m -c charbel password 1001 1001 Charbel Haddad /home/charbel /bin/bash 0 30 15 7:y
useradd -m -c assil p@ssw0rd 1002 1002 Assil /home/assel /bin/bash 0 30 10 5:n
useradd -m -c marwan p@ssw0rd 1003 1003 Marwan Ghantous /home/marwan /bin/bash 0 50 30 7:n
useradd -m -c michel password 1004 1004 Michel /home/michel /bin/bash 1 30 10 5:y
$
```

Now, whether that's a valid invocation of `useradd` that is being echoed is another question altogether, but at least the right data is being processed.

Judging from the man page for `useradd` on RHEL 7.4 (it happens to be the convenient Linux system I have access to), the invocation is badly malformed.  The values mostly need to be prefixed by an option, such as `--comment` or `-c` for the 'comment' field, which is in the `$user_info` variable specified above.  AFAICS, the user name should go last, without a specific option prefix.  But the critical part is reading the data.

Running `useradd --help` as `root` yields:

```
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options:
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                                new account
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
  -D, --defaults                print or change default useradd configuration
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  expiration date of the new account
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       password inactivity period of the new account
  -g, --gid GROUP               name or ID of the primary group of the new
                                account
  -G, --groups GROUPS           list of supplementary groups of the new
                                account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --skel SKEL_DIR           use this alternative skeleton directory
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -l, --no-log-init             do not add the user to the lastlog and
                                faillog databases
  -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
  -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory
  -N, --no-user-group           do not create a group with the same name as
                                the user
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create users with duplicate
                                (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
  -r, --system                  create a system account
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -s, --shell SHELL             login shell of the new account
  -u, --uid UID                 user ID of the new account
  -U, --user-group              create a group with the same name as the user
  -Z, --selinux-user SEUSER     use a specific SEUSER for the SELinux user mapping
```

You would use the `-K` option with appropriate values to specify the minimum and maximum days between password changes.